# Redirecting subdomain to root index.php

Tags: htaccess, domain-forwarding

I am new to this. Here is the situation and I'm wondering if someone can suggest the best solution to it:

I have a domain `www.mydomain.com` where I have a Magento website running, we are in development stage so I did URL forwarding `www.mydomain.com` to `www.mydomain.net` and we have an under-construction page on `www.mydomain.net` because we do not want to show development.

I also have a sub domain `beta.mydomain.com` which I pointed to `www.mydomain.com/index.php` which works fine.

But how can I show this without changing the URL in a browser from `beta.mydomain.com` to `www.mydomain.com/index.php`? This is in order to show our development to management.

Answer (score 1):

This will redirect a subdomain to another domain or root domain

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yoursubdomain\.yourdomain\.com$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [L,R]
```

if you want to show www.mydomain.com/index.php website content to beta.mydomain.com sub domain or beta.mydomain.com website content to www.mydomain.com/index.php?

Simple change domain content path (folder where you website located) from your hosting panel.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, a solution to your problem can be found in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1304492/520779). Assuming you're using a single Apache instance for all your sites, you can tell `mod_rewrite` that you're doing a **rewrite** instead of a **redirect** by removing the `R` flag from the `RewriteRule`:

```
# Example of internal redirect
RewriteRule (.+)$ "?url=$1" [L,R=301]

# Example of internal rewrite
RewriteRule (.+)$ "?url=$1" [L]
```

More info about rewrite vs. redirect in [this thread](http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/3524863.htm). I believe the fact that you're using different domains (or domain/subdomain) will not be an issue, at least I haven't seen anything in [the docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule), but I'm not sure. Quote about absolute URLs:

> If an absolute URL is specified, mod_rewrite checks to see whether the hostname matches the current host. If it does, the scheme and hostname are stripped out and the resulting path is treated as a URL-path. Otherwise, an external redirect is performed for the given URL. To force an external redirect back to the current host, see the [R] flag below.

Now, if you're using a different Apache instance for each site (or some other configuration - I assumed you're using Apache because of the [htaccess](/questions/tagged/htaccess) tag) then I'm afraid I can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use .htaccess and allow only people from your company network (IP's or domain) access to view the website?

Comment: Developers are on different locations and also works from home.

Comment: Then what about setting up an htpasswd protected area so they can all login and view the site?